# Repeat steps from a previous scenario in later scenarios

Tags: python-behave

So I have a scenario outline where I need to repeat those steps in the other scenarios of this feature and I don't want to duplicate the steps manually in feature file.

I tried `Background` but without success yet.

Here is the scenario:

```
Scenario Outline: Adding an item to shopping cart
Given I am on home page
When i browse to category
And i click on the product
And I add <x> product to the bag
Then I should see the <x> in my mini-bag
And I click on the basket to verify if I have <x> items
Examples:
|x|
|1|
```

Second scenario:

```
Scenario Outline: ...
[I want the steps in the scenario above until 
 "Then I should see the <x> in my mini-bag" to be executed here.]
Given I am on the basket
When I edit the quantity to <y>
And I click the apply button
Then I should the quantity <y>
Examples:
|x|
|1|
```

I don't want to use `execute_steps` for all the scenario's which is duplicating in all the steps.

Comment: Your question needed editing so I've edited it. You should take a look at my edit of your second scenario to check whether I understood correctly what you want. It is still not a complete question though. You should add what exactly you tried with `Background` and tell us exactly why it failed.

Comment: Hi, I just added the background like this
Background:
Given I am on home page
When i browse to category
And i click on the product
And I add <x> product to the bag
Then I should see the <x> in my mini-bag

Scenario Outline: